# protractor: How to send a post api request directly for testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Im new to protractor and have a registration page, So i wanted to post the api directly so that the user profile is directly created

My controller

```
<script>
 var app = angular.module("app", []);
 app.controller("HttpGetController", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.SendData = function() {

    var data = {"firstName":"check","lastName":"raq","roles":["PATIENT"],"contactInfo":{"email":"test1@123.com","primaryPhone":"+918598598547","secondaryPhone":null}}     

    $http.post('/ServerRequest/PostDataResponse', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers) {
            $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, header) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status 
        });
    };

});
</script>
```

How should i write a api call for the test case directly.......

Any help is appreciated.........Thanks in advance

Comment: dumb solution - create a button with `ng-click="SendData"` and click it with protractor api

Comment: @ManasovDaniel...could you please code it.......it would be very helpful, as I'm new to protractor